Conversation with children serial killer
A few years ago I watched a very highly rated movie about a serial child rapis/killer. I vaguely remember the story and details but if I remember correctly the movie was south american and the story was about the conversation of a cop with a guy suspected of being a child rapist and serial killer. The cop spoke to the suspect and the suspect eventually convinced him that he was not a serial killer, so the cop let him go. When he left, the cop somehow realized that he actually was the serial killer.
Do you know what movie it was?
Thanks.

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

This is Cronicas. It's actually about a reporter and not a cop who confronts a serial killer suspect...



